# Hardware acceleration for sdk 11, benefits earlier versions?

Tags: android

I know there's hardware acceleration support in android sdk 11 for Canvas. If we build against 11, but target earlier sdk versions, will we get any of that support?:

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="4"
  android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

I watched the google io presentation on this subject, but am not really sure how our Canvas calls are being accelerated. For example, if we're drawing a bunch of lines and circles on a Canvas, are we going to see any performance improvement?:

```
canvas.drawLine(..);
canvas.drawLine(..);
canvas.drawCircle(..);
canvas.drawCircle(..);
...
```

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK hardware acceleration is rather buggy. I faced one of bugs when dealing with `Canvas.drawArc()`. It stopped drawing after some angle. So I wouldn't recommend using it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK versions earlier than 11 would not have the Tegra2 chip required for hardware acceleration.  The code should not crash, but it is an OS-handled function.

In other words, no.

Sorry! :(

Hope this helped.